# Why does iOS kill application (quit with signal 9: Killed: 9) when iCloud switch is changed?

Tags: ios, icloud

I am implementing basic iCloud functions. I monitor changes with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification`.

Whenever I try to turn on or off the switch located in iOS iCloud Settings for my application, my running application is killed by OS. It is not crashing. Here is what I see in the device log:

```
com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.myApp) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.myApp) Exited: Killed: 9
backboardd[30] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.myApp' quit with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

What can be the problem? As there are not errors I am unable to understand it.

May you share your experience I'll b so glad.

Comment: Chances are it is documented to do this, same thing happens when you change the privacy settings for an app.

Comment: This is expected behaviour, the same happens with other permissions such as if the user decides to flip the switch to revoke address book access for an app. Possibly to do with the way the OS provides permissions to running processes so needs to kill them to effect the change...

Comment: It shouldn't get killed, however if you run in debug mode with xcode it does but this seems to be a bug.  Running standalone the app should get sent a notification if the iCloud account changes.

Comment: I would also like to know if this is expected. I tried 3rd party apps downloaded from the AppStore, and it seems that all of them are killed when their corresponding "Documents & Data" switch for that app has been turned ON or OFF. Tried using iOS 7.0.x and 7.1.   Note though that if you turned off "Documents & Data" for the whole device, the app is not killed.